# Using Umbraco to host a HTML5 application?

Tags: .net, html, razor, umbraco

I haven't used Umbraco as yet, however I here good things about it - how it's structured and how easy it is to write "applications" that can be hosted within it (if that is the correct term).

From what I have seen, .NET usercontrols seem to be the way to host "applications", because you can pass down membership info or other params from Umbraco to your hosted usercontrol.

If I want to write a pure HTML5/Javascript (jQuery) app that is to be hosted within Umbraco, what options are available?  I heard that you can create a razor based page (cshtml).. however just wondering how params would be made available from Umbraco to the HTML page itself (I'm not that up on asp.net mvc either, but I am guessing if a razor page, the viewbag could be used?)

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you planning on using Umbraco 4 or Umbraco 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umbraco sounds like a good fit. It lets you use whatever HTML markup you like so you're free to build with it what ever you like.

Umbraco has the idea of *Templates* for rendering whole pages. Templates can be nested additionally each template can have multiple reusable *Macros* which can render out snippets of HTML/XML/JSON.

If you want to do some snazzy JSON calls then they have a RESTful api (not 100% REST though) called /Base which does some goodness.

The juicy bit about Umbraco is the package/plug-in eco-system, there is a great REST package called uREST which gives you some uber power if you need it (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/urest)

Out the box 4.7+ use Razor for their macros (or XSLT or .net User Controls) so plenty of options.

Give it a go. The community forums are supper helpful too (http://our.umbraco.org) if you have a specific problem.

Cheers

Pete

Comment: Hi, and thanks for that very informative update! just what I needed.  At least I can look at the razor page approach, since I am building a module that will be .NET MVC 3 (or 4), and so the idea of those razor macros or whatever to pass info from Umbraco sounds great.  I will check the uREST info too.  Thanks again, very helpful.

Comment: Umbraco are working on some MVC mods for v4 too which should be out by the end of the year (not v5 before anyone comments).